# Postgresql Cost-Based Vacuum Delay parameters

Tags: postgresql, configuration

How to set the these parameters on postgresql.conf ? 
What I should consider while setting them? 
What should I monitor?

```
#vacuum_cost_delay = 0ms                
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1                
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10             
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20            
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200
```

is there any good tutorial or example?

Comment: hello questioner, do you have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postgres [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-VACUUM-COST) are the best place to start

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your system, and what kind of load it has to handle.  Got 100 SSD drives on a SAN with 8Gigs of battery backed cache?  Got a single 5400RPM SATA drive?